# macOS: mouse click MKAnnotationView with modifier key

Tags: swift, macos, mkmapview, mapkit

In my macOS application I want to implement the following behaviour in the MKMapView:

1. Given I have a mapView with multiple annotations
   When the user clicks on an annotation
   Then the annotation is selected
   And the previous selected annotation is deselected
2. Given I have a mapView with multiple annotations
   When the user clicks on an annotation holding the cmd key
   Then the annotation is added to the current selection
3. Given I have a mapView with multiple annotations
   And at least one annotation is selected
   When the user clicks on a selected annotation holding the cmd key
   Then the annotation is removed from the current selection

I'm keeping a separate array of selected annotations, because MKMapView does have a property selectedAnnotations, however that one only contains one annotation at a time.
The first scenario is easy to implement, in the mapDelegate you get a call to the didSelect method. In this method I can add the annotation to my selected annotations array.

But scenario 2 and 3 seem to be impossible. I tried the following routes:

A. Using the delegates' didSelect and didDeselect methods, but the problem is that a second click (not even considering key-modifiers) doesn't lead to a second call of the didSelect method, because at that moment the annotation is already selected.

B. Subclassing MKAnnotationView and overriding the following to take over control of the mapView, but this leads to not showing the callout, or showing the callout on an annotation next to the clicked annotation etc.

```
override func hitTest(_ point: NSPoint) -> NSView? {
        guard let _ = mapView else {
            return nil
        }
        let lPoint = convert(point, from: superview)
        if bounds.contains(lPoint) {
            // Take our own control
            return self
        }
        else {
            // Leave to our superview (the mapView
            return nil
        }
    }

    override func mouseUp(with event: NSEvent) {
        NSLog("MouseDown on \(self.annotation?.title)")
        guard let lGeocache = annotation as? Geocache, let lMapView = mapView else {
            return
        }

        let lCacheAC = TGAppDelegate.shared().cacheArrayController
        if inSelectionSet {
            lCacheAC.removeSelectedObjects([lGeocache])
        }
        else {
            lCacheAC.addSelectedObjects([lGeocache])
        }
        // Show the callout
        lMapView.selectAnnotation(self.annotation!, animated: true)
    }
```

C. You should not subclass MKMapView, but I even tried. However there was no reasonable method to override for this.

Route B came close, but showing the callout was very unpredictable, and therefore unacceptable as solution.

Comment: So want to Cmd-click to show/hide the callout view for multiple annotations?

Comment: @Code Different: No, I want to add/remove annotations to/from my selection when clicking them holding the cmd key. When just clicking an annotation (without key) it should show the callout and replace the selection with the clicked annotation. (just like you can change selection in for example Finder).